# File System API for FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, filesystems, file-storage

I created File System API in a javascript but it`s working fine only on the Chrome. I checked and Firefox does not support funcion like requestFileSystem(). Is there something to request a filesystem from the browser suported by Firefox or other solution to storage files on the browser in Firefox similar to FileSystem from Chrome? I found something like IndexedDB for firefox but i am not sure how to use it in my program only when i am on the Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem API polyfill using IndexedDB: 
https://github.com/ebidel/idb.filesystem.js/